# Update XmlDocument with XElement without using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml

Here's my xml:

```
<settings>
  <Element Name="a" Attribute="b" />
  <Element Name="b" Attribute="c" />
</settings>
```

Here's my code:

```
const string SettingsFileName = "settings.xml";
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
const string RootNode = "settings";
const string elementName = "Element";
const string attributeName = "Name";
const string attributeValue = "b";

xmlDocument.Load(SettingsFileName);
XElement xElement = XElement.Load(new XmlNodeReader(xmlDocument));

var entry = from element in xElement.Elements(elementName)
   where (string)element.Attribute(attributeName) == attributeValue
   select element;

string[] values = { "Attribute", "d" };

xElement = entry.First<XElement>();

for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    string name = values[i++];
    string value = "";
    if (i < values.Length)
        value = values[i];
    xElement.Attribute(name).Value=value;
}
```

I want to update the xmlDocument using the XElement, preferably without using an XDocument. I seem to be missing a step, because this doesn't do it:

```
xmlDocument.Save(SettingsFileName);
```

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update a specific XElement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174792/how-can-i-update-a-specific-xelement)

Comment: edited subject to emphasize: _without using XDocument_

Comment: a simple google search would have yielded many results here is an example for you to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508765/edit-specific-element-in-xdocument

Comment: You'd need to load your changed XML into an `XmlDocument` again. Why are you mixing the two APIs at all?  Just pick one - ideally LINQ to XML.

Comment: Thanks, MethodMan. That and the dozen other possible solutions I've been googling don't work. Try seeing if the solution you found actually solves the problem before saying you have it figured out.

Comment: None of them work because you're opening it with one DOM, then opening it in another DOM, then changing the second but saving the first.  It's not a huge surprise it doesn't work.  What are you trying to achieve here?  Why the two APIs and why the seemingly arbitrary 'no XDocument' requirement?

Comment: Charles, that is very interesting. How does one load the changed XML from an XElement into an XmlDocument?
I tried adding this line before the xmlDocument.Save:
    
    xmlDocument.LoadXml(xElement.ToString());

but that only saves the one element. I want the whole thing updated.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. Thanks for the tip, Charles! Most helpful. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Here's the solution:

```
const string SettingsFileName = "settings.xml";
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
const string RootNode = "settings";
const string elementName = "Element";
const string attributeName = "Name";
const string attributeValue = "b";

xmlDocument.Load(SettingsFileName);
XElement xElement = XElement.Load(new XmlNodeReader(xmlDocument));

var entry = from element in xElement.Elements(elementName)
   where (string)element.Attribute(attributeName) == attributeValue
   select element;

string[] values = { "Attribute", "d" };

XElement xElement0 = entry.First<XElement>();

for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    string name = values[i++];
    string value = "";
    if (i < values.Length)
        value = values[i];
    xElement0.Attribute(name).Value=value;
}
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xElement.ToString());
xmlDocument.Save(SettingsFileName);
```

Comment: This is madness.  Just load it with `XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument`.  You're currently loading in one DOM, loading from that into another DOM, making changes, re-loading back into the first DOM, and then saving.  It's *very* inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really following the 'why' here. What you're doing seems crazy.  Just stick with `XDocument`:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(SettingsFileName);

var attribute = doc
    .Descendants("Element")
    .Attributes("Attribute")
    .Single(x => x.Value == "b");

attribute.Value = "d";

doc.Save(SettingsFileName);
```